# settings not showing in Magento admin

Tags: admin, system.xml, magento2.1.6, acl

I am trying to create a custom module in admin but for some reason modules settings are not appearing. 
Below is my code.

**app/code/Anshu/TrackingImport/etc/adminhtml/system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="Anshu_import" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>Anshu Import Options</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="Anshu_import_section" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Anshu Import Options</label>
            <tab>Anshu_import</tab>
            <resource>Anshu_TrackingImport::trackingimport</resource>
            <group id="ftp_credentials" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>FTP Credentials</label>
                <comment>You must enter your live FTP credentials for this extension to work properly</comment>
                <field id="ftp_login">
                    <label>FTP Login</label>
                </field>
                <field id="ftp_password">
                    <label>FTP Password</label>
                </field>
            </group>
            <group id="cron_settings" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Cron Settings</label>
                <field id="expression">
                    <label>Cron Expression</label>
                    <source_model>Anshu\TrackingImport\Model\Cron</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**app/code/Anshu/TrackingImport/etc/acl.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <resource id="Anshu_TrackingImport::trackingimport" title="Anshu Order Import" sortOrder="51" />
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

**app/code/Anshu/TrackingImport/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Anshu_TrackingImport" setup_version="0.1.0">
        <sequence/>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Anshu/TrackingImport/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Anshu_TrackingImport',
    __DIR__
);
```

It would be great if someone can help me out in finding out the reason and how I can fix it.

Comment: I hope you have run setup command when created the module.

Comment: Yes, I have ran the command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with below format,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="Anshu_import" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>Anshu Import Options</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="Anshu_import_section" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Anshu Import Options</label>
            <tab>Anshu_import</tab>
            <resource>Anshu_TrackingImport::trackingimport</resource>
            <group id="ftp_credentials" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>FTP Credentials</label>
                <comment>You must enter your live FTP credentials for this extension to work properly</comment>
                <field id="ftp_login" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>FTP Login</label>
                </field>
                <field id="ftp_password" translate="label comment" type="password" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>FTP Password</label>
                </field>
            </group>
            <group id="cron_settings" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Cron Settings</label>
                <field id="expression">
                    <label>Cron Expression</label>
                    <source_model>Anshu\TrackingImport\Model\Cron</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Comment: i think you forgot                 <field id="ftp_login" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0"> in your fop login and ftp password.

Comment: But what is the issue here? Are these attributes compulsory?

Comment: Yes,Its used for which type of attribute field like input,select,Boolean(Yes/No)

Comment: If these attributes are compulsory then Magento should throw some exception or error, otherwise it is difficult to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone this may help, it's also possible that your settings aren't showing in admin due to the class not existing that you have configured in `<source_model>` or other model node (e.g. <frontend_model>). Double check this that you have no typos or anything.